# Check if textview is single line

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

I have a textview. I want to check whether it is a single line or not. If it is a single line, I want to remove the icon to the right of it.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/newOrderMessageTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/message_textview_background"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/angle_small_down"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/comment" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if there is a single line with the structure below. Do the action you want to do in the `if`

The reason for using `viewTreeObserver` is to detect whether the textview is ready in the layout.

```
 newOrderMessageTextView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
                ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
                override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                    newOrderMessageTextView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                    val paint = Paint()
                    paint.textSize = newOrderMessageTextView.textSize
                    val width = (paint.measureText(newOrderMessageTextView.text.toString()) + 0.5f).toInt()
                    var lines = width / newOrderMessageTextView.width
                    if (width % newOrderMessageTextView.width > 0)
                        lines++
  
                    if(lines == 1){
      newOrderMessageTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null)
                    Log.e("TAG", "TextView single line")
                  }
                }
            })
```

Comment: yes this worked for me

Comment: you're welcome.

Comment: You can rate my question so that other users can see it too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use viewTreeObserver

```
val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.newOrderMessageTextView)
val iconDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.angle_small_down)

textView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    override fun onGlobalLayout() {
       
        val isSingleLine = textView.layout?.lineCount == 1

     
        if (isSingleLine) {
            textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null)
        } else {
           
            textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, iconDrawable, null)
        }

        // Remove the listener to avoid multiple calls
        textView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
    }
})
```

Comment: This didn't work for me but thank you anyway.
I would be happy if you rate my question.

Comment: Please do not ask for rating, upvoting or points. Makes a bad impression. Behave.